# How to proper calculated one input field and many output field summation?

Tags: javascript, calculated-columns

I have one input field and many calculated output field using JavaScript :[This is output screenshot it's calculated problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnLNA.png)

This is live preview :
http://in-technologii.com/JinChoe/exp2/ if you go this link and input "Base on your annual bill amount :$[input any value]" and see the all output value it's not calculated for proper value. 
i am so tired. i need how to output proper value 
here in my code :

```
function unit_val(){
var arr = document.getElementsByName('unit_val');
var unit_val_tot=0;
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if(parseInt(arr[i].value))
        unit_val_tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
        unit_val_tots =unit_val_tot.toFixed(2);
}
document.getElementById('total_amount').value = unit_val_tots;
document.getElementById('total_amount2').value = unit_val_tots;
}
```

or check view-page-source code.

Comment: You seem to have hardcoded the names and ids of all your rows and fields and there are literally hundreds of them. No wonder you are tired. I suggest you iterate your table and use css selectors and use a library like `jQuery` so that it is easy to iterate and access field and get/set values.

Comment: I couldn't understand your problem. Can you explain a bit?

Comment: same here, what is the correct value?

Comment: @Chinni my problem is : total table 20 row grand total value is wrong.

Comment: Umm. Are you sure you are getting all the elements? Can you check by doing a `console.log()`?

Comment: @chungtinhlakho I need correct value : correct value 20 row summations.
exp : 1.5+2.35+8.32+25.12+.........+9.5 =46.79 but value output wrong value exp : 44.00
how to fix it..?

Comment: @Chinni yes i check it..! but not working please check you view source code and give me proper code and function please.
Thanks.

Comment: you have 4 different columns, show us an example of an input and the results.  you're throwing it there and expect us to figure out the rest.

Comment: grand total is the only thing that is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it I think helpful for you :

```js
function unit_val(){
    var arr = document.getElementsByName('unit_val');
    var unit_val_tot=0;
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        if(parseFloat(arr[i].value))
            unit_val_tot += parseFloat(arr[i].value);
            unit_val_tots =unit_val_tot.toFixed(2);
    }
    document.getElementById('total_amount').value = unit_val_tots;
    document.getElementById('total_amount2').value = unit_val_tots;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

based on what i'm seeing, your grand total is incorrect because you parseint.  you're value has decimal, parseInt will make it become a whole number that's why you're a little off.

```
function unit_val(){
var arr = document.getElementsByName('unit_val');
var unit_val_tot=0;
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if(parseInt(arr[i].value))
        unit_val_tot += arr[i].value;
        unit_val_tots =unit_val_tot.toFixed(2);
}
document.getElementById('total_amount').value = unit_val_tots;
document.getElementById('total_amount2').value = unit_val_tots;
}
```